# Blender problem to set colorspace_setting.name with OCIO colorspaces (Python)

Tags: python, color-management

Mainly I have such a function, which configures the colorspace, right now I put a try method to avoid an error, when the user uses an OCIO colorspace configuration ( https://opencolorio.org/ )

I usually use 2 types of color space, `"sRGB"` and `"Non-Color"`

Example:

```
def set_colorspace_name(img, name):
    # colorspace_names allows you to get the enum list of existing colorspace types, but I have yet to figure out if it is useful to use it
    colorspace_names = [tuple_element[0] for tuple_element in img.bl_rna.properties['colorspace_settings'].fixed_type.properties['name'].enum_items.items()]
    try:
        img.colorspace_settings.name = name
    except:
        pass

img = D.images['My Image']
set_colorspace_name(img, 'sRGB')
```

I am in a dead end, I would like to understand how to set the equivalent of `'sRGB'` and `'Non-Color'` in the OCIO color space, as they will not be present if the user installs this OCIO configuration

Comment: I can't really help here but `[tuple_element[0] for tuple_element in img.bl_rna.properties['colorspace_settings'].fixed_type.properties['name'].enum_items.items()]` can be shortened to `img.bl_rna.properties['colorspace_settings'].fixed_type.properties['name'].enum_items.keys()`

Comment: [Blender manages everything in OCIO by default](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/post_process/color_management.html) and uses a fixed enum of name for [`bpy.types.ColorManagedInputColorspaceSetting`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ColorManagedInputColorspaceSettings.html) but the colorspace [name](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ColorManagedInputColorspaceSettings.html) should be set by the input routines unless you are creating an image from scratch inside blender.  Is that what you are doing?

Comment: At any rate, the name choices are mentioned in the man page I referenced above.  I don't think you can get them from RNA data.